# How can update the Grails ElasticSearch Plugin to the latest Version of ElasticSearch?

Tags: spring, grails, elasticsearch, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I want to use the Grails [ElasticSearch Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) but it seems to be outdated because it uses version 0.17.8.1 of elasticsearch whereas the current released version is 0.90.3.

What do I have to do to update the plugin to the latest version of elasticsearch?

Is it enough to change the follow in BuildConfig.groovy?

```
compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-lang-groovy:1.2.0'
```

to

```
compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-lang-groovy:1.5.0'
```

What else do I have to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate:[here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Comment: Nope, that will just update the groovy API for elastic. You need to update dependency of elastic to the latest one. And make sure they are not breaking change.

Comment: @VijayKukkala how should this help me?

Comment: @dmahapatro can you please post an answer what you would change?

Comment: Sorry posted a wrong link... My bad.. Was referring [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313920/how-to-safely-update-a-grails-plugin)

Comment: Can u tell the steps to add Elastic search plugin in the grails project. I have changed Build config by adding dependency  and I have given DatastoreImpl in config and i have given the static searchable=true in the domain. what next? How to use it in the view . do we need to do anything in the controller
? Exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update [this line](https://github.com/mstein/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L33) to use 0.90.3. I am unable give more details right now as I am using my phone.

Comment: thank you, I would be happy if you give me more hint later, what I have to update.

Comment: by the way would you recommend using the plugin when updating to 0.90.3 or using the groovy api itself?

Comment: what else do I have to change?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the new dependencies are compatible with the plugin, since `elasticsearch` is downloading the dependencies using Grails dependency resolution, you can override them from your application `BuildConfig`. Exclude the plugin from downloading its default and add your desire version from your dependencies closure.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    dependencies {
        // Put any compatible version you want
        runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.90.3'
        runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-lang-groovy:1.5.0'
    }

    plugins {
        compile (":elasticsearch:0.17.8.1") {
            excludes   'elasticsearch','elasticsearch-lang-groovy'
        }
    }
```

Updated : 
https://github.com/alidadasb/elasticSearch

Comment: No downloaded it for the first time.

Comment: The plugin will not be installed with your solution!

Comment: I get the following error: Plugin release-3.0.0 requires version [2.3 > *] of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet. Please try install a different version of the plugin or Grails.

Comment: This is related to your grails version and release-3.0.0 plugin. What version of grails you are using?

Comment: I use grails 2.2.4 in ggts 3.3 Kepler

Comment: Are you using release-3.0.0 plugin with 2.2.4? If so as the error is telling you can only use that version with grails 2.3>* not 2.2.4

Comment: no I do not use the release plugin, I do not know why dis is comming?

Comment: Probably one of the plugins you are using is using it. Posted a link to sample program that works fine with it.

Comment: I downloaded the source and find that it could not wokr. If you upgrade the dependencies you have to change some function names.